# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.StatelessSession.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/Query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-batch

Any idea why would I get this error:

Sourcecode:

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public HibernateCursorItemReader<OrderDetail> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['orderDate']}") final String orderDate) throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, Exception {
        LOGGER.info("START of reader() with args: ", orderDate);
        final Date beginDate = new Date();
        final Date endDate = new Date();
        final Map<String, Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<>();
        parameterValues.put("beginDate", beginDate);
        parameterValues.put("endDate", endDate);

        final HibernateCursorItemReader<OrderDetail> itemReader = new HibernateCursorItemReader<>();
        // TODO: explore if we can use HibernateQueryProvider -- itemReader.setQueryProvider(HibernateQueryProvider)
        itemReader.setQueryString("select dtl from OrderDetail dtl join OrderSummary sumy on dtl.summaryId = sumy.id where orderDate between :beginDate and :endDate order by id desc");
        itemReader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);

        itemReader.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        itemReader.setUseStatelessSession(true);

        itemReader.afterPropertiesSet();

        LOGGER.info("END of reader()");

        return itemReader;
    }
```

> Error StackTrace :-

```
     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
     org.hibernate.StatelessSession.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/Query;
        at
     org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.createQuery(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:151)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.getForwardOnlyCursor(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:125)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader.doOpen(HibernateCursorItemReader.java:185)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ebb633d0.invoke(<generated>)
        at
     org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at
     org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
        at
     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at
     org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
        at
     org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
        at
     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at
     org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8b5472d5.open(<generated>)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
        at
     org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at
 org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at
     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
     org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
        at
     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
        at
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at
     org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
        at
     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at
     org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy151.run(Unknown Source)  at
     com.optum.otgs.ie.eligibility.controller.EligibilityController.generateParisExchangeFile1(EligibilityController.java:586)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at
     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at
     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at
     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        at
     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at
     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at
     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at
     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at
     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)     at
     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at
     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at
     org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at
     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at
     org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
        at
     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at
     org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at
     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at
     org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:186)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at
     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at
     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at
     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
        at
     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at
     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at
     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
        at
     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at
     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: what version of Hibernate library do you use???

Comment: hibernate-core 5.0.12.Final

Comment: r u using spring boot ?

Comment: yes I do, spring-boot 1.5.6.RELEASE

Comment: looks like problem of version compatibility between `spring-batch` and `hibernate`. Try to upgrade or downgrade version of `hibernate` and-or `spring-batch`

Comment: Okay. When I googled for this issue, looks like some one has compiled spring-boot with a specific version of hibernate to resolve the issue, but not sure how they did that compilation!